# Magento: Retrieving uncached system configuration values

Tags: php, magento

I have a script that sends order data to a 3rd party system via a RESTful web service. This system demands that a unique ID is sent with each request, which is autoincremented from the next.

I've implemented this by adding a variable for this in Magento's `core_config_data` table, and as part of my code the function below is called to get the next value for the ID, incrementing it for the next request.

```php
class MyProject
{
    public function getNextApiId() {
        // Get the next ID.
        $id = Mage::getStoreConfig('myproject/next_api_id');

        // Increment the stored value for next time.
        $nextId = $id + 1; // change $id++ by $id + 1 otherwise the result of $nextId = $id - 1;
        Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('myproject/next_api_id',$nextId);

        // Refresh the config.
        Mage::getConfig()->cleanCache();
        Mage::getConfig()->reinit();

        // Return the ID.
        return $id;
    }
}
```

If I send one request with my script, this works fine - the value is incremented and the next ID is used for the next execution of the script.

However, the value appears to be cached if I'm processing multiple requests in a loop within the same script execution. The code below should illustrate the general flow, though I've reduced it for brevity:

```php
function sendRequest($item) {
    $apiId = $MyProject->getNextApiId();

    // Build and send request body
}

foreach($items as $item) {
    sendRequest($item);
}
```

This would result in the initial ID number being used for all `$items`.

The `cleanCache()` and `reinit()` attempts to refresh the config cache do not seem to work at all. Any ideas on how to stop the value from being cached?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cache must be cleaned in a different way, you have to reset the cache of the store and init it again cause of the loop. If you didn't have a loop, it will be cleaned also but it needs  a second url request of the shop which will init the cache.

Try this instead:

```
function getNextApiId() {
    // Get the next ID.
    $id = Mage::getStoreConfig('myproject/next_api_id');

    // Increment the stored value for next time.
    $nextId = $id + 1;

    Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('myproject/next_api_id',$nextId);

    // Refresh the config.
    Mage::app()->getStore()->resetConfig();

    // Return the ID.
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: Reason for downvote? Looks similar to what I originally had, though it uses `Mage::app()->getConfig()` rather than `Mage::getConfig()`. Could make a difference, will try it out.

Comment: @CVM it's nice to explain why you down voted. Yes, `Mage::app()->getConfig()` and `Mage::getConfig()` are similar. I brought the solution from a code I had, that's the reason of the change but that's the same. However, the method `$config->app()->reinitStores()` this is a solution provided by Drew Hunter, we were working on the same way but my code was not perfect although I thought it was because I had similar problem as you and in my case it worked. As suggested Drew to me, his code works in loop context. I have found an alternative that I edited in this answer.

Comment: @CVM I forgot, it's better for performance reason to use `Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig()` instead of `Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig();` it does the same but in the first case it use the singleton and don't create a new instance.

Comment: I was actually asking why it was downvoted - I didn't downvote it myself. Trying your revised solution, `Mage::app()->getStore()->resetConfig();` has worked perfectly and appears more specific than `Mage::app()->reinitStores();`, which I would guess influences more than just the config. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why go to all this bother - reading and writing to db, clearing config cache etc - if you simply require a unique id to be passed to an api?

There are lots of ways to do this in PHP, here is one:

```
$uniqueId = uniqid();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Otherwise, if you must create your id's using the method in your question then make sure you are saving your config correctly:

```
Mage::getConfig()
    ->saveConfig('myproject/next_api_id', $nextId)
    ->cleanCache();
Mage::app()->reinitStores();
```

Comment: @SylvainRayé - afraid not, sorry. Part of the code is similar yes, unfortunately there is no way around this since it is relatively standard code with no real alternative.  Also you missed some vital code in your solution.

Comment: Well ok I apologize. I checked again and you're right. However there is a bug in the code of the author. it should be `$id +1` and not `$id++` otherwise the result will be `$nextId = $id - 1`

Comment: Good spot on the bug. While reducing the code for use on here I made this mistake. My original code has `$nextId = $id + 1;`.

The unique ID needs to be incremented from the previous value, which was not clear in my original question. Have made an edit to reflect this.

I'll give `reinitStores()` a shot, see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

The Magento config is intended for values which do not change often, values which change the behavior of something. Not only does storing this value in the config not align with the purpose, but it will introduce performance problems into the site. Every time you clear the config cache the site will have to relayer the config files into the cached XML document which is stored in the cache, and this will introduce unnecessary delays to the load time of the site.

My suggestion would be to do one of the following:

a. Use a UID based on a generated pattern incorporating your process ID and the unix timestamp (microseconds).

b. Use a core variable model to store your value in: `Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('myproject_next_api_id');`

My warning with option 'b' would be that if you have any possibility that this script may have multiple instances running simultaneously, you *will* run into race conditions which necessitate storing the ID on record in the database which you update via a custom atomic update query.

Comment: Option A would not be feasible, the client is very particular that we increment using specific values. Option B would work, and there would be no issues with race conditions in this particular case - there is one script that will reference the ID and it runs on cron every 20 minutes. Upvoted for a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple alternative:

```
protected function _getLastId()
{
    $id = Mage::app()->useCache('config') ?
        Mage::getResourceModel('core/config_data_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('path', self::XML_PATH_LAST_ID)
            //->addFieldToFilter('scope', $scope)
            //->addFieldToFilter('scope_id', $scopeId)
            ->getFirstItem()
            ->getValue() :
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_LAST_ID);
    return (int) $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer, and many other that involve clearing cache, are a complete shame, because `Mage::app()->getStore()->resetConfig();` will cause `Mage::getConfig()->reinit();` which is something you should mostly call... never!

It will trigger Magento to completely re-parse XML configuration, and this is **dead slow**, and more so with the increasing number of the plugins and their configuration files.

I've seen some plugin developers copy-paste stuff like this and end up bringing tremendous performance issues to whoever uses those plugins. Not by merely using those codes (that too), but also skillfully managing to stuff those codes to be called upon every request, effectively causing config cache efficiency to decline to 0!

Why clear the entire config cache if you can simply update what's changed?

```php
Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('foo', 'bar'); 
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('foo', 'bar')->saveCache();
```

The first line updates config item for the request's lifecycle only (runtime cache)

The second line ensures the same is saved to `core_config_data` and updates the cache.

But either way, the answer by @davidalger rightfully states that `core_config_data` is meant for rarely changing data.